# Can someone explain me the difference of these two type of angular controller declarations.

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```js
angular.module('hackApp',[])
.controller('technologyController', technologyController);

function technologyController($scope) { 

$scope.heading = "Choose your technology";

}


angular.module('hackApp',[]) .controller('technologyController',function($scope) 

{ 

$scope.heading = "Choose your technology"; 

}
```

Can someone explain me what these two type of angular declarations means?

Comment: These essentially do the exact same thing, just two different styles. Although you should probably use $inject.

Comment: These **are** the same thing. Either you init controller with referenced named function or with inline anonymous function.

Answer (score 0):

Those are pretty much the same declaration.

On the second one though, you are passing an anonymous function instead of a named function.

Particularly for AngularJS there is a style guide that covers precisely that: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y024

You might want to take a look at the style guide overall if you are new to AngularJS.